# Changing the 'disabled' attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have a problem with a button attribute. It does not matter whether YES or NO is changed. I suspect the problem here is `button.disabled` because it does not highlight the word "disabled".

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
    var button = document.getElementsByName("button");
    var regulamin = document.getElementsByName("accept");
 
  //console.log(button);

   for (var i = 0; i < regulamin.length; i++)
   {
       regulamin[i].onclick = function()
       { 
        //alert(this.value === "true");  <-- here is OK
           button.disabled = (this.value === "true");  <-- not OK
       };
   }

};
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `button[0].disabled` try this

Comment: Console.log (button) gives 1 element (there is one button on the page) and it is set to disabled: true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
    var button = document.getElementsByName("button")[0];
    var regulamin = document.getElementsByName("accept");
 
  console.log(button);

   for (var i = 0; i < regulamin.length; i++)
   {
       regulamin[i].onclick = function()
       { 
        //alert(this.value === "true");  <-- here is OK
           button.disabled = (this.value === "true");  
       };
   }

};
```

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
    </div>
       <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

`getElementsByName` reutrns an array of element having the same name. So you need to choose which element you want. You have only one button so you can access the element like `document.getElementsByName("button")[0]`

Comment: WOW thank you very much :)

Comment: @DownVote , can you share it why so???

Comment: I do not know why I reacted like this .. I clicked on UP .. I'm sorry

Comment: @KamilFajbuś Happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

You could

- target your named radio buttons
- forEach → assign a `change` event handler
- retrieve the `.closest` (parent) `form`
- than go back down the DOM and find your `type="submit"`

[image: Chrome icon]
[image: Firefox icon]
[image: Edge icon]
[image: Opera icon]
[image: Safari icon]<sup>**9**</sup>

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[name='accept']")).forEach( radio => {
  radio.addEventListener("change", function() {
    this.closest("form").querySelector("[type='submit']").disabled = this.value === "true";
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

With the above you can even have **multiple forms** on a single page - since the   encapsulated DOM traversing.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[name='accept']")).forEach( radio => {
  radio.addEventListener("change", function() {
    this.closest("form").querySelector("[type='submit']").disabled = this.value === "true";
  });
});
```

```html
<h3>Multiple forms</h3>

<form>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>

<form>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>

<form>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="button" disabled>REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your button from a "name" to an "id" and then get its element by "id". See the code below. The button toggle on the no yes now works correctly.

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <div>
            <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="true" checked>NO</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="accept" value="false">YES</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="button">REGISTER</button>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var regulamin = document.getElementsByName("accept");
    button.disabled = true;
    //console.log(button);

    for (var i = 0; i < regulamin.length; i++) {
        regulamin[i].onclick = function () {
            //alert(this.value === "true");  <-- here is OK
            if (button.disabled) {
                button.disabled = false;
            } else {
                button.disabled = true;
            }                
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote; its a different way of approaching the problem but this code does work

Answer (score -2):

I think your name property of input element is same and you are getting **getElementByName**. Its getting both as true.

Try to give other input element with different name property.

Comment: Console.log (button) gives 1 element (there is one button on the page) and it is set to disabled: true

Comment: If I click on "NO" the alert returns False but does not assign it to the button attribute